# How to select indices according to another tensor in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensors a and b. And I want to retrive the values of b according to the positions of max values in a. That is,

max_values, indices = torch.max(a, dim=0, keepdim=True)

However, I do not know how to use the indices to retrive the values of b. Can anybody helps to solve it? Thanks a lot!!

Edit:

Sorry for not describing my problem concretely. To give a minimal example, the value of tensors a and b are:

```
    a = torch.tensor([[1,2,4],[2,1,3]])
    b = torch.tensor([[10,24,2],[23,4,5]])
```

If I use `torch.max(a, dim=0, keepdim=True)`, it will return:

```
    max:  tensor([[2, 2, 4]])
    indices:   tensor([[1, 0, 0]])
```

What I want to obtain is the selected value of tensor b according to the indices of max values of a in `dim=0`, that is,

```
    tensor([[23, 24, 2]])
```

I have tried `b[indices]`, whereas the result is not what I want:

```
    tensor([[[ 2,  3,  5],
             [10, 30, 40],
             [10, 30, 40]]])
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal and precise example.

Comment: Your question needs more details. Just from what you have provided, it seems that `b[indices]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have provided a minimal example. Sorry for the inconvinience. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html):

```
torch.gather(b, dim=0, index=indices)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This function could perfectly solve my problem.